# Integral of area of a circle, physical significance

Tags: integration, geometry, soft-question

The integral of the circumference of a circle is its area:
$$\int 2\pi*r = \pi *r ^2$$

Likewise, does the integral of area have physical significance?
$$\int \pi *r ^2 = \frac{\pi*r^3 }{3}$$

(Its similar to the volume of a sphere, but its only 1/4 of that, so that seems coincidence. )

Comment: Not one that I .know of, but a pattern does generalize to higher dimensions: The integral of the surface area of a sphere $\int 4\pi r^2 =\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ is the volume of a sphere. When you think about it, that's the better analogy... the surface area of the sphere is like the circumference of a circle in one higher dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the volume of the cone with height equal to $r$. You have originally your disk made out of increasing radius rings. In this case you have a cone made out of increasing radius disks